# Why does ARM assign addresses to registers like this?

Tags: assembly, arm, low-level, arm64

As you can see in the following snippet of ARM64, this just happens to be from the kernel for iOS 10.

```
fffffff0073de41c         adrp       x22, #0xfffffff0075ef000
fffffff0073de420         ldr        x0, [x22, #0x330]
```

Why does it load a specific address like the one above? `0xfffffff0075ef000 + 0x350`, since it's precompiled would it not make sense to just load the entire address `0xfffffff0075ef330`.

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Either because no single instruction can encode loading the entire address  or there are multiple addresses formed using the same base. I don't know the specifics of ARM64 but you can't fit any arbitrary 64-bit address into a 32-bit wide instruction.

Comment: @RossRidge So how is the base stored or how is it acknowledged by the machine?

Comment: It's stored in X22 which can used by later instructions. Say something like `ldr x1, [x22, #0x10]`

Comment: Are there any instructions between adrp and ldr. If so, adrp could be loop initialization.

Comment: would need to see more, this is likely taken out of context.

Comment: What specific platform is this snippet from?

Comment: 5.3.4 Address Generation
ADRP Xd, label
Address of Page: sign extends a 21-bit offset, shifts it left by 12 and adds it to the value of the PC with its
bottom 12 bits cleared, writing the result to register Xd. This computes the base address of the 4KiB
aligned memory region containing label, and is designed to be used in conjunction with a load, store or
ADD instruction which supplies the bottom 12 bits of the label’s address. See ARMv8 Instruction Set Overview for more.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic iPhone 7 iOS Kernel 10.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the entire address you would need more instructions (in general, you need 4 instructions to load a 64 bit immediate value).

The purpose of the ADRP instructions, possibly in cooperation with ADR, is to be able to use the address of symbols with less instructions than loading an immediate value would need.

Comment: And to allow position-independent code that can access within a fairly wide range, large enough for any code to access any static storage in .data or .bss up to a reasonable size limit.